# dm-crypt with LUKS - /etc/crypttab using either keyfile or passphrase

Tags: linux, luks, dm-crypt

I have my home partition encrypted using dm-crypt and LUKS header. I have two slots in its header: first one is a passphrase and second is keyfile. I have keyfile on external drive which I use only as 'encrypting device'. My `/etc/crypttab` looks like this:

```
# <target name> <source device>  <key file>              <options>
home            UUID="..."       /dev/sdb1:/home.key     luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev,discard
```

Now everything works well, but I'd like my computer to ask me to type passphrase in case it cannot find device with keyfile. I've tried to add `home` to `crypttab` twice. First record was configured to use passphrase and had `timeout` in options. Second one was that presented above. It doesn't work.

Is there any possibility to configure system in this way?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a fallback pass on slot 1 -- will post link to tutorial i use fom gentoo forums but in a nutshell pipe stdin (your kf) to a fifo which forces pass request  you get a kf +pass and a fallback pass (in slot 2)

```
SLOT 1:   keyfile + pass
SLOT 2:   fallback pass (if slot 1 is unreachable /corrupt or its pass suffwrs same fate)
```

Comment: In `/etc/crypttab` I have to decide if I want to use keyfile or passphrase (rules from this file are used during boot process). I need Linux to ask me for passphrase if it doesn't find keyfile. Now, if it doesn't find keyfile it stops booting and I can do nothing.

Comment: You misunderstand  '/etc/crypttab'  generate a fallback passphrase  an leave your crypttab as is